# css how to add established class selector

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors

THIS IS A CAFE MENU PAGE

trying to make the "Est. 2020" text italicized by creating an established class selector and giving it the font-style property with the value italic.
THIS is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cafe Menu</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <main>
        <h1>CAMPER CAFE</h1>
        <p>Est. 2020</p>
        <section>
          <h2>Coffee</h2>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">French Vanilla</p><p class="price">3.00</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Caramel Macchiato</p><p class="price">3.75</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Pumpkin Spice</p><p class="price">3.50</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Hazelnut</p><p class="price">4.00</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Mocha</p><p class="price">4.50</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h2>Desserts</h2>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="dessert">Donut</p><p class="price">1.50</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="dessert">Cherry Pie</p><p class="price">2.75</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="dessert">Cheesecake</p><p class="price">3.00</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="dessert">Cinnamon Roll</p><p class="price">2.50</p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

THIS IS THE CSS CODE

```
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/css-cafe/beans.jpg);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.p-established {
   font-style: italic;
}


h1, h2, p {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-family: Impact, serif;
}

.item p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.flavor, .dessert {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.price {
  text-align: right;
  width: 25%
}
```

trying to make the "Est. 2020" text italicized by creating an established class selector and giving it the font-style property with the value italic.

Comment: In HTML use <p class="established">Est. 2020</p> and in your CSS use p.established {...} And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your HTML to add a class to `<p>Est. 2020</p>` element.
It needs to be  `<p class="established">Est. 2020</p>` for you to be able to customize it with CSS. The moment it has the `.established` class then you can add

```
.established {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

If you are working only with CSS and can't change the HTML code then let me know.

//////////////////////////

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/css-cafe/beans.jpg);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Impact, serif;
}

.item p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.flavor,
.dessert {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.price {
  text-align: right;
  width: 25%
}

.established {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Cafe Menu</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <main>
      <h1>CAMPER CAFE</h1>
      <p class="established">Est. 2020</p>
      <section>
        <h2>Coffee</h2>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="flavor">French Vanilla</p>
          <p class="price">3.00</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="flavor">Caramel Macchiato</p>
          <p class="price">3.75</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="flavor">Pumpkin Spice</p>
          <p class="price">3.50</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="flavor">Hazelnut</p>
          <p class="price">4.00</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="flavor">Mocha</p>
          <p class="price">4.50</p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>Desserts</h2>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="dessert">Donut</p>
          <p class="price">1.50</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="dessert">Cherry Pie</p>
          <p class="price">2.75</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="dessert">Cheesecake</p>
          <p class="price">3.00</p>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <p class="dessert">Cinnamon Roll</p>
          <p class="price">2.50</p>
        </article>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks figured it out. had to add the established class in html as well